# Python how to apply bag of words to tweets in csv file

Tags: python, twitter, scikit-learn, nlp, nltk

I am currently working twitter data analysis and have been working on applying bag of words technique in Python and have been having no luck.
Currently I have been able to stream data to be stored in a database with some preprocessing which I then export the tweets into a csv file but stumbling on the next part to use bag of words in order to do machine learning.

I've tried following https://www.kaggle.com/c/word2vec-nlp-tutorial#part-1-for-beginners-bag-of-words however I have had no success and haven't been able to grasp an understanding how how to approach by just looking at either scikit or nltk documentation. Can anyone advise tutorials I can follow to achieve bag of words with Python 3? 
Thanks for the help

Comment: Start with this first: https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/basic-nlp-with-nltk then maybe the Word2vec tutorial is easier to digest.

Comment: Thanks for the link. That looks really useful as it breaks down each step with a description. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So scikit-learn's [CountVectoriser](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#the-bag-of-words-representation) is a good place to start. You'll want to create a vocabulary of some fixed size (N unique words collected from your tweets) so that you can represent each tweet as a fixed length vector, where each position in the vector represents a particular word from your vocabulary, and the value is the number of times that word has appeared.

With pure Python this would be:

1. Create an array of tweet texts
2. Initialise an empty set representing your vocabulary

*First pass through tweets*

3. For each tweet, extract unique words

   - Add these words to your vocabulary if they don't exist

*Second pass through same tweets*

4. For each tweet, extract unique words

   - Create a vector filled with zeros of size N representing the tweet
   - For each word, increment the count corresponding to the position of the word in the vector

You could use 1 or 0 for a word being present or not instead of word frequencies. See what works.

However, scikit-learn makes all of this much easier to do.

I found [this tutorial](https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/bag-of-words/) which might help too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and help.